# Using jedi-vim with venv picks wrong files

Tags: jedi-vim

I'm trying to use vim with jedi-vim on a python project using setuptools and venv.
When using goto definition it only finds the files under venv/python3.11/site-packages.

This is of no use when I want to edit the file. I have searched high and low but cannot find a way to exclude the venv directories.
I expected jedi to find the files in the src tree that are checked into git, not the pip installed ones.

Any pointers are gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: You should probably add an issue in the jedi-vim issue tracker. What you want to do clearly works and you probably have some sort of misconfiguration that is not possible to understand here with the limited information you provided.